# Shouldn't automatic bounties go to the most upvoted answer?

Tags: support, bounty

I answered this question ([XNA game will not run in VMWare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27081301/xna-game-will-not-run-in-vmware)) which had a bounty on it. The question already had an answer. I answered it anyway and received many upvotes for my answer. This was because I provided more detail than the other guy and actually engaged the asker to try and solve his problem.

Nevertheless, the other guy got the bounty simply because he answered first, not because he had more upvotes, not because he detailed how to solve the problem, not because he actually tried to help the guy.

Shouldn't automatic bounties go to the most upvoted answer?

Comment: The bounty wasn't awarded automatically. It was  awarded **manually** by the OP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bounties are already set to be automatically awarded if the OP doesn't select an answer.  From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount. If two or more eligible answers have the same score (i.e., their scores are tied), the oldest answer is awarded the bounty. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.

In this case, there were 2 answers posted after the start of the bounty and the [OP selected the other answer to receive the bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27081301/revisions).  The bounty will only be automatically assign **if the OP doesn't award it** and the answer meets the criteria above.

Comment: pffft blue footed bird, how dare you answer better than me!  (for curiosity, is there a way for a normal user to know if a bounty was awarded vs auto-given?)

Comment: @Patrice [Looking at the revision history of the post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27081301/revisions) - it says _Bounty Ended with BradleyDotNET's answer chosen by Ted_

Comment: @bluefeet How do you get the revision history for a post? Is there a link somewhere on the post? Or do you have to edit the URL? I know how to get it when a post has been edited, but I couldn't find it anywhere in a non-edited post.

Comment: @RetoKoradi The question # is the same as the "post #".  So just type in stackoverflow/posts/POSTNUMBER/Revisions.  Seems to be enough :)

Comment: @RetoKoradi the tool tip of the bounty award describes the awarding scenerio, so just hover over the +50

Comment: @psubsee2003 Sure, but I still wanted to know how bluefeet accessed that revision history. I didn't even know that posts that had not been edited had a visible revision history.